# Conference Room Input Devices?

Tags: hardware

I really need to find a good wireless mouse and keyboard combination for a conference room.  I've used a few that seem to need to be within 5 feet of the receiver... which doesn't work as the conference room is 24' x 18'.  Also a long battery life is key as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Really, pushing off topic and subjective but I really like Logitech products.  Check out the [Logitech MX5500](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/keyboards/keyboard-mice-combos/devices/3481).

It's bluetooth 2.0, which should provide an approximate 10 meter range without line of site.  The mouse comes with a replaceable and rechargeable AA battery, which can be placed in a docking station provided with it.  You could also purchase [low discharge NiHM rechargeables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel-metal_hydride_battery#Low_self-discharge_cells), which would allow the keyboard similar functionality.  As an added bonus, the product is aesthetically pleasing.

Ultimately, most bluetooth wireless keyboard and mice should satisfy your requirements as long as they are not on the low end.  RF tends to be less effective in longer range applications.

Be wary about security too, as you could potentially risk restricted data input via the devices.  Historically, the protocols used are notoriously insecure.

Comment: How is the battery life on it?

Comment: $170.00 US is a little pricey for a mouse\keyboard combo that's going to sit in a corporate conference room, IMHO.

Comment: @Joe, a corporate conference room, in my opinion, should have the nicest stuff, because that's what your visitors are going to see. We've got the MX5000 set (very similar to MX5500) and apart from actually being really good, they look the part when paired with a 50" LED TV.

Comment: @Farseeker: Well it's been a while since I've been in a stuffy corporate conference room, so I'll give you that one. The 7 of us at my company usually just eat lunch in our conference room and take bets on when the air conditioner is going to go on the fritz again. :)

Comment: I'm really tempted to buy this... But the problem is I hear this Keyboard doesn't have an off switch.  A conf room isn't going to have people on the keyboard all the time... Isn't this a problem?

Comment: They usually timeout/sleep.  Try it out.  If you don't like it, return it.  :)

Comment: We have a Logitech wireless keyboard in our conference room without an on/off switch that lasts about 4-6 months between battery replacements (used at least once a week).

Comment: That's what we use in our conference room. Works great at around 20 feet from the pc.  We had an RF keyboard/touchpad combo and it was far from responsive.  The boss threatened to throw it out of the window on a weekly basis.

Answer (score 3):

Bluetooth gives you 30 feet and much better mouse response but costs more than RF.

Comment: Bluetooth is really the way to go in this situation.

Comment: Beware of Bluetooth keyboard eavesdropping / keystroke loggers.

Answer (score 3):

I have had good results with [Gyration](http://www.gyration.com/index.php/us/home.html) products for this application (conference rooms).

The "gyro control" is a cool feature, and experienced presenters will get the hang of it, but it isn't a reason to buy the device. The reliability, distance, good battery life, and durability are reasons.

They sell them at CDW, and Buy.com happens to have a [keyboard/mouse combo](http://www.buy.com/prod/gyration-intelligent-airmouse-featuring-motionsense-with-a-gyration-go/q/loc/101/214413910.html) for a huge discount. I suspect it is last years model!

Comment: +1 vote for Gyration. I have used them in the past in conference rooms, and they have great signal and battery life.

Comment: +1 - I have also had good experiences with this solution at considerable distances.

Comment: My vote is for Gyration.  Dumped the bluetooth Logitech keyboard/ mouse combo in favor of a Gyration keyboard/mouse combo.  Couldn't be happier.

Comment: The end users have seemed to like their products but I've been less impressed personally.  They generally strike me as gimicky and less useful over time.  The "laptop keyboard" they have for workstations is kind of cool though.

Answer (score 1):

Rosewill wireless keyboard/mouse. It has incredible range, much better than the Microsoft products I've used. We use it in our conference room, not sure of the specs, but it's a huge four-section conference table. You can sit at the end of it and control the PC which is located in a cabinet on the other side of the room.

Comment: Microsoft wireless keyboards seem to have a shorter range than my left arm.  What's with that?

Comment: I have this one MS wireless one, and yes. You are correct. If it's more than an arms length away, it's choppy and can't be used.

Comment: I would like to third this sentiment.  Microsoft wireless products are a waste of time if extended range is one of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

After trying 3 different cheap RF keyboard/mouse units, we ended up with the Logitech MX5500. We found many of the RF units had very poor range in our office. The MX5500 has worked very well for the last 9 months or so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Apple fanboy, but you might want to look at the Apple Stainless steel wireless keyboard and multi-touch pad.

They are sleek and elegant and may fit your conference room decor. As well, they fit onto a podium nicely without needing much room.

Also, for batteries, you **MUST** get some of the new Sanyo eneloop batteries. Duracell rebrands them (they have white tops) if you can't find the Sanyo batteries. I believe Apple is using a similar (or perhaps also rebranded) tech for their new battery line.

They're great because they keep a charge when not in use.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the Microsoft Presenter 8000 series (I believe the mouse that comes with it is actually a 5000 series).

The mouse is comfortable, comes with a rechargeable battery and docking station.
The keyboard is extremely slim, has all the media and web controls you could need.

The set comes with a USB bluetooth connector, but I have also successfully (easily) used it with true bluetooth and left the dongle at home. It isn't cheap, and I usually avoid Microsoft peripherals, but this one was worth the purchase for my own presentations and home theatre.